# Can the help center article on beta be changed for graduated sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center

I noticed that one of the articles in an SE site's help center is "What does "beta" mean?" It gives a quick run-down of all the important information about beta sites. This is helpful for new users on beta sites.<sup>1</sup>

The article (which is similar, if not the same, in many non-trilogy sites) starts off with

> This site was created through the open democratic process at  Stack Exchange Area 51, and it is currently in beta.

That's all well and good, but it seems that some graduated sites still have that phrasing. Some examples are [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta) and [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta). There are others, of course.

On the other hand, sites that were *not* created via Area 51 do not have the message. [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-beta) just begins with

> We create beta sites through the open democratic process at  Stack Exchange Area 51.

The same goes for [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta).

Moderators can edit *some* help center articles (such as the on-topic/off-topic pages), but I can't edit the page on [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-beta), even though I'm a mod (as per [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198350/a-mod-only-section-of-the-help-center?rq=1), I believe - only some sections are editable). So it's fixed.

I realize that it's something minor, and that not many users will ever reach the page, but can that be changed when a site graduates?

---

<sup>1</sup>For those that go through the help center, that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be changed by community managers, either for all sites network-wide, or for one site at a time. So I made a decision a while back to update the wording to have this page make sense on all sites, beta or graduated. This was purely to save myself some work, because it means the Community Team no longer has to create it manually when a site first launches and remember to delete it when it graduates.

This should have been unremarkable, except I overlooked the part that says "and it is currently in beta". I've updated the text so that it now makes sense on all sites without overrides, regardless of beta status:

> This site was created through the open democratic process at Stack Exchange Area 51. Sites created through this process begin in “beta”, which means that the site is still being defined and constructed. There are a few differences between beta and non-beta sites...[continues unchanged]

The only sites with the alternate wording ("We create beta sites through...") are the special cases that did not ever come through Area 51, like the trilogy, MSE, MathOverflow, etc.