# Add a section in the mod help center about redactions

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, help-center

The [mod-only help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198350/294691) is helpful, especially for new moderators. It contains information that mods need (and a warning not to copy stuff out).

One of the most commonly asked things in the TL is how to redact posts. [(1)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4?m=38548239#38548239) [(2)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4?m=38229812#38229812) [(3)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4?m=37086353#37086353) [(4)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36740667#36740667). It's not intuitive at all. So, what could be a better thing to put in the mod help center than something that lots of mods have trouble with?

Comment: Are you supposed to link to mod only chatrooms? I was explicitly told not to share links to mod-only rooms. Or is this a test for SE employees to see how easy they can find the info on how to redact this post?

Comment: @rene - you can link to it - it's linked several times on meta - just search for 'Teacher's Lounge'. If you click on that link, you won't see anything - but mods will. Also, it won't onebox in chat.

Comment: You're lucky, you're right: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6154014#6154014

Comment: Can you see [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146735/conversation/redacting-revisions)?

Comment: Nope, @BhargavRao.

Comment: Damn, I should  have created it on the SE chat instead (so that all mods could have seen it)